# How to Migrate RabbitMQ server to new CentOS 7 server

Tags: centos, rabbitmq

Does anyone here have any experience with the migration of RabbitMQ(v3.5.3) to new servers? I currently have two RMQ servers in a cluster on old systems and I want to migrate them to new virtual machines. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any direct migration tool for it.

It looks like the easiest way to do it, is to add the new servers to the cluster, let them replicate everything and after replication has completed successfully, shut down the old servers.

Is there a way to export/import from old servers to new? Even if there was, I'm quite worried about my ability to setup the new servers exactly like the old.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Shovel Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) for seamless migration or backup definitions, configs and mnesia database on one machine and restore them on other.

TL;DR;

The idea is to run new cluster and migrate all entities, e.g. via management interface (web - see [Management Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) docs or cli - see [Export configuration section](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) or even this SO question [RabbitMQ : how to create and restore backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635165/rabbitmq-how-to-create-and-restore-backup)).

Then you seamlessly migrate with shovel plugin messages from one cluster to another.

Alternatively, you may take directory with RabbitMQ data (see [File Locations](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html) docs for standard paths) from one cluster to another, but this way may have some caveats, as node namings, mnesia and erlang versions, etc., see this users group discussion for details - [RabbitMQ server Mnesia backup and restore](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/SCUeiCgnhAA).